# TV set without internet?

Tags: television

Can you get a standalone TV set these days that

- works without an internet connection to show free British TV channels
- works without requiring a subscription, account, password, or any kind of user identification or verification
- shows you what's being broadcast on a few channels as soon as you put enough electrical current through its plug at the right voltage, in whatever place a person decides to do that, assuming there's a signal
- does not communicate outwards with any device, or inwards with any device (even a remote control) other than the transmitter
- can be bought in a shop for cash

?

I would be interested in recommendations both for TV sets proper that meet these criteria and also for three-part hardware arrangements that collectively meet them, comprising a box to receive the signal, a cable, and a monitor to watch it on.

Comment: I'm not sure that a television without built-in IR for remote control use is even available anymore. Best bet is to get a non-smart TV , an antenna/digital converter box kit, and then just open the monitor housing and hardware disable the IR yourself (read: just rip it out or snip the wires). I would try to find a popular model so that you can look up the IR receiver placement more easily.

Comment: The built-in IR can be easily disabled, though it baffles me why you want to do that. It can't send data, and the TV can't be flashed over IR. In any case, it's just a little 3-5mm diode behind some shaded plastic, easy to remove. All last-generation TVs have some means for direct control via capacitative touch or buttons. I recommend an older Sony Trinitron CRT, though the box for signal really depends on what programs you want. Satboxes are receive-only.

Comment: Rather than buying a TV set and turning it into a monitor, could I not get an antenna and tuner with an HDMI output and feed it to an HDMI input of a simple monitor, adjusting the tuner when I want to change channels, or are there major drawbacks with that idea? Just 10-15 of the British "Freeview" channels listed near the top of [this page](https://www.freeview.co.uk/why-freeview/channels#yP1ktHCrygfbOjPI.97) would be fine. Does "last-generation" mean "most recent but one" generation, or "most recent generation"? (Please excuse my ignorance.)